# LPTHW EX25, I think there's something wrong with my powershell? Even when copy and paste

Tags: python

So copied this into a file called ex25.py -

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Now in Blueshell, cd to where the folder resides, and type 'Python' to activate python, and just copy/paste this code from Zed's website -

```
import ex25
sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
words
sorted_words = ex25.sort_words(words)
sorted_words
ex25.print_first_word(words)
ex25.print_last_word(words)
words
ex25.print_first_word(sorted_words)
ex25.print_last_word(sorted_words)
sorted_words
sorted_words = ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
sorted_words
ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
```

Results (my problem) -

```
>>> import ex25
>>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
>>> words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
>>> words
['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
>>> sorted_words = ex25.sort_words(words)
>>> sorted_words
['All', 'come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.', 'who']
>>> ex25.print_first_word(words)
All
>>> ex25.print_last_word(words)
wait.
>>> words
['good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who']
>>> ex25.print_first_word(sorted_words)
All
>>> ex25.print_last_word(sorted_words)
who
>>> sorted_words
['come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.']
>>> sorted_words = ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sort_sentence'
>>> sorted_words
['All', 'come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.', 'who']
>>> ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
All
wait.
>>> ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ex25.py", line 33, in print_first_and_last_sorted
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
NameError: global name 'sort_sentence' is not defined
>>>
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help! Have wasted the last 40 mins on this -__-

Comment: Try `dir(ex25)` to explore the module and make sure `sorted_words` is in the returned just, without funny extra characters, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it was because I originally had a typo in my function sort_sentence.I had to quit out of Python and re-open so that it imported  `ex25` again and it worked.